# A general, centralized parameter logger method, in C#

Tags: c#, logging, parameters

Consider this JavaScript code snippet:

```
Object.prototype.log = function() {
   // here, you have a centralized place to do logging stuff;
   console.log(this);
}

function fullName(firstName, lastName)
{
    // here, using a simple one-line code, you can log all parameters;
    arguments.log();
}

fullName('saeed', 'nemati');
```

Can we have a similar mechanism for logging all the parameters passed into a method, in C#?

**Note**: What I've done was to use reflection, but with no success:

```
public static void LogParameters(this ParameterInfo[] parameters)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.Append("*****************\r\n");
    builder.Append("Parameters\r\n");
    parameters.ToList().ForEach(pi =>
    {
        builder.AppendFormat("{0} => {1}\r\n", pi.Name, pi.DefaultValue);
        // The problem is that, I can't get the value of the parameter here
    });
    builder.Append("*****************");
    Log.Write(builder.ToString());
}

public string GetFullName(string firstName, string lastName)
{
    MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().GetParameters().LogParameters();
    return firstName + " - " + lastName;
}

GetFullName("saeed", "neamati");
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you can't obtain parameter values using reflection. You'd have to pass them into the logging method explicitly.

You may be able to do this using the debugger API, but you probably don't want to. I would just do it explicitly if I were you - and in fact, that's likely to end up with more useful logging, as you can log only what's important, and give some context in a message as well.

Comment: How sad, and how bad. AMAIK, PHP also has an `arguments` object. I don't know. If I could do that, I would have a greater flexibility in troubleshooting live application problems by seeing the value of the parameters passed to them, while at the same time, I shouldn't write many lines of code per method. :(

Comment: @SaeedNeamati: If you're troubleshooting a live application, you'd normally want *targeted* logging, explaining the context and *relevant* arguments. Personally I don't think I'd find it useful.

Comment: yeah, you're right. But many times (not sometimes ;)) I really get tired of writing many lines of codes to log something. For example, we already have an extension method working on type **Exception** and we simply log our exceptions using `ex.Handle();`, which is of course, elegant, brief, centralized, developer-friendly, etc. :)

Comment: @SaeedNeamati: I wouldn't write a method which just *logs* an exception and call it *handle*. Logging an exception really isn't the same thing as handling it. You shouldn't have to write "many lines of code to log something". If you find that you really need *that* much diagnostic information, it sounds like you don't have sufficient confidence in how the code is executing. Do you have unit tests? They work a lot better than just having a lot of logging, when it comes to confidence :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/) and AOP. Here's an example which also logs the parameters of a method call.

http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/WebDev/ServerProgramming/using-postsharp-and-log4net-to-set-up-co